# How do I cast to a void (*)(int,int,int) in C++?

Tags: c++

To keep it very simple I have a function that passes `void (*)(int,int,int)` how do I cast to it as a parameter?

example: `Function(void (*)(int,int,int) );`

I'm expecting to pass parameters here but I got no idea what they are

Comment: Please post the actual code, including the declaration of the function you're trying to pass a function as a parameter to.

Comment: Might be useful to `using fnptr_v_iii = void (*)(int,int,int);` or some more semantically meaningful name.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration of `Function` expects you to pass it the address of a free function (i.e. one not bound to the instance of a class) that takes three parameters of type `int`. You didn't specify a return type for `Function` so for this example I'm going to assume it is `void`.

```
#include <iostream>

void Function(void (*)(int, int, int));

void DoSomething(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout << "DoSomething called with a=" << a << " b=" << b << " c=" << c;
}

int main()
{
    Function(DoSomething);
}

void Function(void (*callback)(int, int, int))
{
    std::cout
        << "Function called. Now calling 'callback' at address "
        << callback 
        << "\n";

    callback(1, 2, 3);
}
```

In this example `main` calls `Function` by passing the address of function `DoSomething`. The implementation of `Function` then calls the function it is passed (named `callback`) and passes 3 arguments `1`, `2`, and `3`.

The result is the following

```
Function called. Now calling 'callback' at address 00511F55
DoSomething called with a=1 b=2 c=3
```

You should not need to do any casting to call `Function`. If you encounter an error or start believing that you should perform a cast to call it you're about to do something terribly wrong.

Comment: I have to do casting as the function is a pointer to a pointer function that reads an address to a function resulting in my function calls being complicated. So Typedef ->Pointer Function(request access to real function) -> Objectfunction (results in casting to function nightmare)

Comment: You should edit your post to include those missing details and some example code and I'll update my answer to reflect what you need to do and/or tell you why what you're doing won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```cpp
Function(static_cast<void (*)(int,int,int)>(fp))
```

You might alternatively need `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` depending on what you're casting...

Comment: No the Function input parameter is : void (*)(int,int,int)

Comment: Casting here is a good way to introduce undefined behavior.

Comment: `static_cast`ing to a function pointer is impossible if it isn't a redundant identity conversion or implicit qualifier conversion. Everything else requires a `reinterpret_cast` and will then cause undefined behavior when `Function` actually calls it with the wrong type.